# Is two separate index equals to a composite index?

Tags: mysql, index, innodb

For example, this is a sample table

```
id int PK,
pid int,
cid int,
deleted int,
createdAt timestamp,
UNIQUE KEY pid_cid(pid, cid)
```

used WHERE clauses are

```
where pid=$pid and cid=$cid [and deleted = 1];
where pid=$pid [and deleted = 1];
where cid=$pid [and deleted = 1];
```

since I have indexed `UNIQUE KEY pid_cid(pid, cid)`, should I index on pid and cid separately?

Or selecting by a `index pid` faster than selecting by a `UNIQUE KEY pid_cid(pid, cid)`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Two separate index is not the same as a composite. Although MySQL now has index merge other than analytical queries it's not very efficient.

In your case the best to have the unique key and a single column index.

Start the composite with the higher cardinality column. If `pid` has more distinct values than it's good as it is. If `cid` has more than I would suggest to use `UNIQUE KEY (cid, pid)`. Also create a separate index which is only the column that is the second in the unique key.

For example

`UNIQUE KEY (cid, pid), KEY (pid)`
or
`UNIQUE KEY (pid, cid), KEY (cid)`

This way:

- `where pid=$pid and cid=$cid [and deleted = 1]` will use the UNIQUE KEY

One of these will use the composite unique key the other will use the single column index.

- `where pid=$pid [and deleted = 1];`
- `where cid=$pid [and deleted = 1];`

### Alternative solution

You can make the composite index the `PRIMARY KEY` and have a single key on the other column:

**Pros**:

- Very fast lookup on `PRIMARY KEY`
- No need for an extra ID
- Rows will naturally be clustered around the first column of the `PK`:

Since you have queries where you only have one of the column `cid = X` or `pid = X` these rows will be close(r) to each other so InnoDB needs to read less pages. Which can significantly speed up multiple rows resulting queries.

**Cons**:

- Every index will have the PK concatenated to it so if you have a lot of secondary indexes this can consume some space.
- If neither pid or cid are in incrementing order your `INSERT` throughput will suffer

Comment: In this case: `UNIQUE KEY (cid, pid), KEY (pid)`,  `KEY(cid)` is not necessary?

Comment: No, `KEY(cid)` is covered by the unique key. Fields are kind of concatenated (for lack of a better word) in the index and prefix search is possible.

Answer (score 3):

No.  But I will say something different than Károly Nagy.

`UNIQUE` and `PRIMARY KEY` not only index the column or columns indicated, they provide a uniqueness constraint.  `UNIQUE(cid)` only says that `cid` shall not be duplicated.  `UNIQUE(cid, pid)` says that the *pair* of values shall not be duplicated in the table.  That is, `cid` may be duplicated, but only with different values of `pid`.

Let's back off of uniqueness for a moment.

```
WHERE pid=123  -- INDEX(pid) works well;
          so does INDEX(pid, cid) -- in this  order
WHERE pid=123 AND cid=456  -- INDEX(pid, cid) or INDEX(cid, pid) works best
```

That is, the order of columns in the `INDEX` matters, but the order in of clauses in the `WHERE` does not.  [*More*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql) and [*more*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index1) .

Your sample table looks like a many-to-many mapping table.  If so, I advise that you follow the rest of the tips [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table) .

A `PRIMARY KEY`, is appropriate, is faster than a `UNIQUE` key since it is "clustered" with the data.

Using a second index as `INDEX(cid, pid)`, even though `INDEX(cid)` is just as good and the pair is unique is better because it is "covering" (unless you need to check `deleted`) and it avoids unnecessarily checking uniqueness during inserts.

I suggest that you will eventually decide that `deleted` and `createdAt` are not worth the bother.

For the 6 different `WHERE` clauses you mention, I suggest this set:

```
PRIMARY KEY(pid, cid)  -- do not include `deleted`; this declares the pair unique
INDEX(cid, pid, deleted)
```

The perfect list would include about 4 indexes, but I don't think it is worth it.  These two handle even the worst of the 6 cases adequately well.